# Can't match any option in bash select statement

Tags: bash

I'm trying to use the bash `select` statement for a command loop. The variable in the select statement is always blank. Here is a simple script that illustrates the problem:

```
#!/bin/bash

select term in one two exit
do
  echo you selected $term
  case $term in
    one ) echo one; break;;
    two ) echo two; break;;
    exit ) echo will exit; return;;
  esac
done
```

Here is what happens when I run this script:

```
$ ./test.sh 
1) one
2) two
3) exit
#? one
you selected
#? two
you selected
#? exit
you selected
#? ^D
```

Anyone know what I might be doing wrong? I'm on Mac OS X 10.7.3. `/bin/bash --version` shows: GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin11)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The script works if you type in "1" or "2" rather than "one" or "two".

Answer (score 6):

@jedwards gave you the immediate answer. However, if you want to protect yourself from other users having the same error, you could do something like this

```
select term in first second exit; do
  [[ -z $term ]] && casevar=$REPLY || casevar=$term. # or, shorter, casevar=${term:-$REPLY}
  case $casevar in
    1|first) echo "the first option"; break ;;
    2|second) echo "option no. 2"; break ;;
    3|exit) echo bye; break ;;
  esac
done
```

Note this from the bash manual:

> a line is read from the standard input. If the line consists of a
>   number corresponding to one of the displayed words, then the value of
>   name is set to that word. If the line is empty, the words and prompt
>   are displayed again. If EOF is read, the select command completes. Any
>   other value read causes name to be set to null. The line read is saved
>   in the variable REPLY.